# What is the conventional architecture to propagate data updates to many ViewControllers?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I'm working on an app with three views that are all on screen at the same time and which share the same data model, a Swift object which also has child objects. Each view presents the data in a different way and affords the user ways of modifying that data such as re-ordering items, adding/removing items, etc. Additionally, certain user actions trigger asynchronous updates to the model such as fetching additional information for items from an API. My goal is to find an architecture that allows me to inform each view's controller of updates to the data without having to imperatively communicate between view controllers.

What is the conventional approach to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Common approaches are to subscribe to `NSNotification`s that notify observers that an update has occurred:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateData:) name:kAppDidUpdateDataNotification object:nil];
```

Then the data source can send notifications to subscribers:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kAppDidUpdateDataNotification
                                                    object:object];
```

Another approach is to have a shared data source and use [Key Value Observing](http://nshipster.com/key-value-observing/) on it. KVO lets you subscribe to updates on a `keyPath` (like a property on your data source). KVO is a little hairy—I recommend using a library that wraps it into something that supports blocks, or maybe consider a framework like [ReactiveCocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa) that has similar properties. Note that you can also [observe changes to collections](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOCompliance.html) with KVO, which is nice if you have e.g. an `NSMutableArray` of items with multiple table view controllers displaying them, and you want to do things like animate the deletion of rows at specific indexes as objects are removed from the array. Since you mentioned re-ordering and adding/removing items, this could be an especially good fit for you.

Comment: thanks for the answer. ReactiveCocoa is something we considered but with the project being in a very volatile state we're a little hesitant to go all-in on it; not to mention the cognitive overhead of switching to such a dramatically different programming paradigm. NSNotificationCenter seems simple enough, but the more fine-grained observation of KVO seems ideal for our use case, as you mentioned. Do you know if there are any swift libraries that wrap KVO to make it less hairy?

Comment: I'm not super familiar with Swift, so I'm not sure what libraries are best to use.

Comment: Based on my research this does seem to be the conventional approach

Answer (score 0):

Add a list of delegates to your data model, and whenever an event happens, loop through the list and notify its delegate. This is an extension of Objective-C delegate pattern, and is very similar to notification center's `addObserver`/`removeObserver`.

```
protocol DataModelDelegate {
    func dataModel(dataModel: DataModel, didFetchData data: String) // Or any other events
}

class DataModel {
    private delegates = [DataModelDelegates]()

    func addDelegate(delegate: DataModelDelegate) { delegates.append(delegate) }
    func removeDelegate(delegate: DataModelDelegate) { // Remove `delegate` from `delegates` }

    func dataFetched(data: String) { // Or any other events
        for d in delegates { d.dataModel(self, didFetchData: data) }
    }
}

...

class ViewController1: UIViewController, DataModelDelegate {
    private dataModel: DataModel!

    init(dataModel: DataModel) {
        ...
        self.dataModel = dataModel
        dataModel.addDelegate(self)
        ...
    }

    deinit {
        // Retain cycle without this!
        dataModel.removeDelegate(self)
    }

    func dataModel(dataModel: DataModel, didFetchData data: String) {
        // Update UI, etc
    }

}
```

Notification center will also do the job, but IMO notification center should be used only for loose-coupling cases (ie the notification sender and notification receiver don't know each other well); if your view controllers have an intimate knowledge about their shared data model, then delegate / multiple-delegate is a better approach.

Also, depending on your problem, data model's life time may be independent of its view controllers (as a singleton, for example), or is managed by one of the view controllers.